# Decimal To Binary Python R2L format

Tags: python, recursion, binary

I'm trying to convert an integer to a R2L binary format list using recursion. I keep getting an error that the int object is not iterable. Here's my code,

```
def decimalToBinary(x):
    list1 = []
    if x == 0:
        return []
    elif x > 1:
        list1 += 0
        return decimalToBinary(x//2)
    else:
        list1 += 1
        return list1
```

I don't get the problem, please help!!

update: changed the code to this:

```
def decimalToBinary(x):
    list1 = []
    if x == 0:
        return []
    elif x > 1:
        list1 += [0]
        return decimalToBinary(x//2)
    else:
        list1 += [1]
        return list1
```

and it's returning `[1]` if I enter 8, which should return `[0,0,0,1]`.

Comment: if you want to append item to list use `.append`, dont use + between int ans list

Comment: i tried using that and it just returns [1], for some reason it returns nothing

Comment: take a look at my answer, I think that's what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

First as I wrote, you shouldn't sum up `int` and `list`.
second, there is no reason to implement it in recursion, you can implement it like so:

```
def decimalToBinary(x):
    binary_rep = []
    while x!=0:
        binary_rep.append(str(x%2))
        x=int(x/2)
    binary_rep.reverse()
    return binary_rep
        
print(decimalToBinary(50))
print(int(''.join(decimalToBinary(50)),2))
```

output:

```
['1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0']
50
```

second method is to use conversion of string representation of int to binary like so:

```
n=50
print(bin(n).replace("0b", ""))
```

output:

```
110010
```

is the recursion is a must go implementation?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the premade `bin()` function!

```
def decimal_to_binary(x):
    return bin(x)[2:]

print(decimal_to_binary(12))
```

will print `1100`

or, using the list() function:

```
def decimal_to_binary(x):
    return list(bin(x)[2:])


print(decimal_to_binary(12))
```

prints: `['1', '1', '0', '0']`